# Undefined offset in php with json

Tags: php, json

i was trying to use league of legends api and convert champion id to his name the code :

```
  public function GetChampName($id)
  {
    $summObj = $this->getJSONObj('https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/na/v1.2/champion/' . $id .'?champData=image&api_key=' . $this->apikey . '');
    $summID =  (string) ($summObj[$id]["key"]);

    return $summID;
   }
```

and use like that :

```
                      $championid = $summoners[$i]['championId'];
                      $championName = $LolApi->GetChampName($championid);
```

$summoners is a array of participants in a current-game api.

when im doing

```
var_dump($championName)
```

im getting int(99) int(37) int(28) int(21) int(80) for example , and when im trying to use it like i said :

```
                      $championid = $summoners[$i]['championId'];
                      $championName = $LolApi->GetChampName($championid);
```

Im getting this errors :

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 99 in F:\xampp\htdocs\tilt\LolApi.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined offset: 37 in F:\xampp\htdocs\tilt\LolApi.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined offset: 28 in F:\xampp\htdocs\tilt\LolApi.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined offset: 21 in F:\xampp\htdocs\tilt\LolApi.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined offset: 80 in F:\xampp\htdocs\tilt\LolApi.php on line 24
```

line :

```
$summID =  (string) ($summObj[$id]["key"]);
```

any idea how to fix it ? , i will provide anything needed to fix it.

Comment: Can you echo $summObj from GetChampName and show me what the output is?

Comment: @ArunLodhi i did var_dump : array(5) { ["id"]=> int(37) ["key"]=> string(4) "Sona" ["name"]=> string(4) "Sona" ["title"]=> string(20) "Maven of the Strings" ["image"]=> array(7) { ["full"]=> string(8) "Sona.png" ["sprite"]=> string(13) "champion3.png" ["group"]=> string(8) "champion" ["x"]=> int(288) ["y"]=> int(0) ["w"]=> int(48) ["h"]=> int(48) } }

Comment: This is 1 of the var_dump

Comment: I think you should use `$summID =  (string) ($summObj["key"]);` instead of `$summID =  (string) ($summObj[$id]["key"]);`

Comment: @ArunLodhi thx , fixed ;)

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted.. Glad to help :)

Comment: @ArunLodhi http://pastebin.com/RXF22uHQ can you check it? , getting same error.

Comment: I think `$losses = (string) ($summObj[$id][0]["entries"][0]["losses"]);` should do it because "31524077" and "entries" both are arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear from var_dump that the array you are receiving is of the format:

```
[
    "id"=>37,
    "key"=>"Sona"
]
```

and so on. You should use

```
$summID = (string) ($summObj["key"]);
```

to get the name instead of

```
$summID = (string) ($summObj[$id]["key"]);
```